# instance based regex in python

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is already available a library which does something similar to scrapely

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapely

WHat it does is that you give an example url and then you give the data you want to extract from that html..

```
url1 = 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/w3lib/1.1'
data = {'name': 'w3lib 1.1', 'author': 'Scrapy project', 'description': 'Library of web-related functions'}
```

and then you initiate this rule by simply:

```
s.train(url1, data)
```

Now, I can extract the same data from different url...

But is there any library which does the same but for raw text...

For example:

```
raw_text = "|foo|bar,name = how cool"
```

And then I want to extract "bar" from this.

I know, I can write a simple regex rules and get done with this.. but is there any library available which solves this as an instance based learning problem..

i.e rather than specifying a regex rule and then passing data over it..

instead I specify an instance and what I would like to extract and it automatically builds rule ?

Hope that I am making some sense.

Comment: related: http://txt2re.com/

Comment: some theory: [On Learning Regular Languages](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/on-learning-regular-languages/). Note: in practice, it might be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you like scrapely, you can use it. First, convert the text to something that resembles html, for example by replacing all relevant markers in the text with `<br>`.  Then do what is done in the Scrapely `train` method, except fetching the html from a remote location.

If that works well, the scrapely guys will probably like your pull request on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to fly under the radar with this answer because you already deleted the post that the actual question was for: creating a nested dictionary/json in python

Well, I solved it to work on my Python and this is what I came up with.

```
import re
from itertools import chain

d = {'foo': ['a', 'b'], 'foo::bar':['c'], 'foo::bar::baz':['z'], 'foo::baz':['f'], 'bar' :['d'], 
'bar::baz': ['d', 'a'], 'boom':[], 'boom::bam::boombam' : ['foo']}

dic = {}
hiers = {}
for k,v in d.items():
    if '::' not in k:
        if not v:
            dic[k] = {'inner_tag':{}}
        else:
            dic[k] = {'sources':v, 'inner_tag':{}}
    if '::' in k:
        hiers[k] =v

it = iter(hiers)
i = next(it)

def reg(i):
    return[m.start() for m in re.finditer('::',i)]

for k,v in dic.items():     
    while True:
        try:            
            nxt = next(it)      
            it = chain([nxt], it)               
            curr_len = len(reg(i))
            nxt_len = len(reg(nxt))
        except StopIteration:
            v['inner_tag'][i] = {'sources':hiers[i]}
            break
        if curr_len <= nxt_len and i[:2] == nxt[:2]:
            v['inner_tag'][i] = {'sources':hiers[i], 'inner_tag':{}}    
            last = i
            i = next(it)    
        elif i[:2] != nxt[:2]:
            v['inner_tag'][i] = {'sources':hiers[i]}
            last = i
            i = next(it)
            break
        else:
            v['inner_tag'][last]['inner_tag'][i] = hiers[i]
            last = i
            i = next(it)            
            continue                                

print(dic)
```